# FHIR and null flavors

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am trying to understand how FHIR handles null flavors in comparison to CDA. [Here](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/comparison-v3.html), FHIR says that "FHIR approaches the problem differently. Null flavors are only introduced in the core specification in those circumstances where it is expected that most systems will need them. Where needed, the flavors are constrained to those relevant to that element."

What does this mean? Does this mean that FHIR allows null flavors only in some circumstances, i.e., in some resources where it is expected that most systems will need them? But in my reading of FHIR so far where I came across several resource I found none with null flavor.

Or is it the case that FHIR does not at all allow null flavors and if one needs it, extensions should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed the case that if one needs nullFlavours, extensions may be used.

When we wrote "Null flavors are only introduced in the core specification in those circumstances where it is expected that most systems will need them" we expected our resources to have "real" elements in places where nullflavours are common (but then with a more useful name, e.g. "tooSmallToMeasure" in an Observation). This did happen to the v3 "negation" indicator, which was for example turned into an element Procedure.notPerformed.

As it turned out sometimes nullFlavors are explicitly allowed or required, but this is not done in the general specification but only in profiles and Implementation Guides, where their use is detailed and the circumstances in which they may appear is explicitly documented.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, that statement is sort of obsolete in that null flavours are no longer part of the cores specification (i.e. there are no resources that have null flavour elements). Rather extensions and profiles can be used to achieve this.

With negation indicators, they are, unlike null flavours, part of the core specification in that they are part of resources where it is thought most likely that they maybe needed.

Comment: There is Observation.dataAbsentReason - that is a nullFlavor. I think there's no other place where it was deemed actually useful, though you will also find many value sets that include some null flavors

Comment: @Ewout: How to handle a case when null flavor is required in an extension? For example, MU2 requires ethnicity and religion codes to be present and those are provided as extensions in the Patient resource. However, if say the religion code is not known, can null flavor be used instead?

Comment: Hi @user3005941, it depends: generally in FHIR, we now design valuesets so the values for "unknown" (or more specific flavours) are now part of the valid choices for that valueset.  However, if this is not the case, you can use the dataAbsentReason extension (http://hl7.org/fhir/extension-data-absent-reason.html) on the "value" (valueCodeableConcept most of the time) element of the race and religion extensions.  Of course, implementation guides and profiles may explicitly forbid this, I don't know whether this is the case in MU2.